# IL Code operation Could Destabilize the runtime

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, il

I current have the following code when i run it i get the error code Operation could destabilize the runtime (this my updated il code the matches the sigil it still does not work though)

```
public static Func<IDataReader, Object> TestMethod<T>()
    {
        var method = new DynamicMethod("", typeof(Object), new[]
        {
            typeof ( IDataReader )
        });
        var il = method.GetILGenerator();
        Label whileIf = il.DefineLabel();
        Label whileStart = il.DefineLabel();
        Label methodEnd = il.DefineLabel();
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, typeof(List<string>).GetConstructor(new Type[0]));
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Br_S, whileIf);
        il.MarkLabel(whileStart);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof(IDataRecord).GetMethod("GetString"));
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof(List<string>).GetMethod("Add"));
        il.MarkLabel(whileIf);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof(IDataReader).GetMethod("Read"));
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Brtrue_S, whileStart);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        return (Func<IDataReader, Object>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<IDataReader, Object>));
    }
```

It was created from this code:

```
public List<string> method(IDataReader dataReader)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();
        while (dataReader.Read())
            result.Add(dataReader.GetString(0));
        return result;
    }
```

Which Genearates the following IL code:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  newobj      System.Collections.Generic.List<System.String>..ctor
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // result
IL_0007:  br.s        IL_0017
IL_0009:  ldloc.0     // result
IL_000A:  ldarg.1     
IL_000B:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_000C:  callvirt    System.Data.IDataRecord.GetString
IL_0011:  callvirt    System.Collections.Generic.List<System.String>.Add
IL_0016:  nop         
IL_0017:  ldarg.1     
IL_0018:  callvirt    System.Data.IDataReader.Read
IL_001D:  stloc.2     // CS$4$0001
IL_001E:  ldloc.2     // CS$4$0001
IL_001F:  brtrue.s    IL_0009
IL_0021:  ldloc.0     // result
IL_0022:  stloc.1     // CS$1$0000
IL_0023:  br.s        IL_0025
IL_0025:  ldloc.1     // CS$1$0000
IL_0026:  ret
```

I am writing this code in IL as i will eventually extent the code the dymaicly create this code to populate a type from a TArg. Sorry i have no more information that all that visual studio gives me.

This is my sigil code which works and runs correctly:

```
var emiter = Emit<Func<IDataReader, List<String>>>.NewDynamicMethod("MyMethod");

            var whileIf = emiter.DefineLabel("whileIf");
            var whileStart = emiter.DefineLabel("whileStart");

            emiter.DeclareLocal(typeof(List<string>), "0");

            emiter.NewObject<List<String>>();
            emiter.StoreLocal("0");
            emiter.Branch(whileIf);
            emiter.MarkLabel(whileStart);
            emiter.LoadLocal("0");
            emiter.LoadArgument(0);
            emiter.LoadConstant(0);
            emiter.CallVirtual(typeof(IDataRecord).GetMethod("GetString"));
            emiter.CallVirtual(typeof(List<string>).GetMethod("Add"));
            emiter.MarkLabel(whileIf);
            emiter.LoadArgument(0);
            emiter.CallVirtual(typeof(IDataReader).GetMethod("Read"));
            emiter.BranchIfTrue(whileStart);
            emiter.LoadLocal("0");
            emiter.Return();
            Func<IDataReader, List<string>> result = emiter.CreateDelegate();

            Disassembler<Func<IDataReader, List<string>>>.Disassemble( result );

            return result;
```

Comment: Are you familiar with `AssemblyBuilder`? If you use that to create your method, you can save the assembly to disk, and run PEVerify on the generated assembly. This will usually tell you what's wrong.

Comment: no but thanks I will look into it do you have a small snippet of code as an example ?

Comment: Not right now, but when I can, I'll check back and post something if you don't have a good solution yet.

Comment: Pro tip: when compiling to check IL, build in release mode - not debug

Comment: Second pro tip: unless you are doing this for fun, consider using tools like dapper which handle all this stuff for you

Comment: I am currently doing this for fun as i already have code that generates this in c# and then compiles it on the fly which is faster than native code after the code is compiled, but i want to do it in il to reduce the compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually means either a stack imbalance, or the wrong kind of call (static vs. virtual). I'm not at a pc to check the stack state, but: I strongly suggest using a tool like "sigil" if you are unsure. It is designed explicitly to tell you **as soon as you make a mistake** in the emit, rather than when you run it later. It will tell you exactly the problem as soon as you make it.

These are definitely the wrong way around, though:

```
    il.Emit( OpCodes.Ldarg_0 );
    il.MarkLabel( whileIf );
```

The first time through it branches direct to whileIf, which has you doing a call on an empty stack.

Comment: What's a `call vs virt.`?

Comment: @Gabe static call vs virtual call

Comment: i have looked into sigil and wrote my il in it and it runs perfectly any ideas what the problem could  be thanks .

Comment: @Jake did you fix the broken branch I spoke about?

Comment: Im slightly confused at what you mean why would it be calling an empty stack? And if this is the problem why does the same il code work in sigil? thanks

Comment: @Jake "callvirt" requires at least one item on the stack - the target object reference. It also requires all the parameters (there are none for Read) - you need to load a value before calling callvirt, and your original IL doesn't. I can't comment on the sigil code without seeing it, but my guess is: you reversed the 2 lines I cited

Comment: @Rote yup, exactly what I said: in the sigil code you mark then load, rather than load then mark; allow me to look smug a moment...

Comment: @MarcGravell i just updated the question with my current code it still does not work :/

Comment: @Jake am not at a pc right now - il emit needs a debugger... Will look when I have a pc

Comment: @jake I can definitely find it - I'm just not at a PC (for info, I'm the insane person behind the IL-emit in "dapper" and "protobuf-net") - will update you when I have a debugger

Comment: @JakeRote you use `ldloc_0` / `stloc_0`,  but you don't declare any locals... add `il.DeclareLocal(typeof(List<string>));` to the top and you should be sorted (note: you do declare this in the sigil version)

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks how silly of me how did you I not notice that

Comment: @Jake if I had a coin for every time I couldn't see something that a second set of eyes could see trivially...

Answer (score 0):

When I was writing a lot more IL, I wrote these helper method that let me create delegates and also at the same time generate debug assemblies. Having the assembly is useful to run reflector tools as well as PEVerify.
https://bitbucket.org/mburbea/delegatedproxy/src/483a0120ff845379898ffad790082c62e43efb4e/Utilities/CodeGen.cs?at=master

Here is my implementation, I basically never changed it between my various projects.